# New line in the fields content

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a normal field:

```
<field id="my:nameAnswer" ...
```

that has a textarea inside.

When I write some text in the textarea, if I make a new line, then, when I return the value with: `document.getElementById("x").value;`, does not returns me the text with new line. Instead, it returns the text without any new line.

I tried to add this on field of the textarea:

```
<control-param name="saveLineBreaks">true</control-param>
```

But without success.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @hRdCoder , yes. But same problem. In fact, I put it here the example with parentheses but I have no parentheses in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem of configuration of field in Alfresco. I got the solution.

I have to add this parameter in the field:

```
              <control-param name="saveLineBreaks">true</control-param>
```

If anyone needs.